# Should I pick a constant sample size for regressions on data with different available n?

Tags: multiple-regression, sample-size

I am using OLS to estimate the effects of various factors on the sales of different items. The data are monthly, and vary somewhat in the number of monthly observations available (some of the items have only been sold for, say, 18 months while others have data going back for years).

Should I pick some n (e.g. 18) and stick with it for modeling all the products? This option is appealing because I'm more interested in more recent effects and because unmodeled and difficult-to-know-about factors might be present in the more distant data. Also, I'm getting good fits and high significance for the relevant variables even with the smaller sample sizes, so I don't "need" to increase the sample size from that perspective.

I will need to produce reporting on this periodically, so a desirable property would be that parameter estimates are fairly stable from report to report. This is a possible argument for using the larger sample sizes where available.